# Validates Uniqueness Method to follow only one time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise

I create a following system exactly like that with users (Devise).
I followed the Ryan Bates Rails casts http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

In this code we can add numerous times the same user, I want to block when people has added as a friend.

For example when User1 has added a User2 the link will be block.
I give you some codes to understand.

The migration is called FriendShip

```
class CreateFriendships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :friendships do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :friend_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

The model for users is

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
```

The model for Friendship is

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
```

The Friendship controller

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
  def create
  @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(:friend_id => params[:friend_id])
    if @friendship.save
      flash[:notice] = "Added friend."
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      flash[:error] = "Unable to add friend."
      redirect_to current_user
    end
  end

def destroy
    @friendship = current_user.friendships.find(params[:id])
    @friendship.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Removed friendship."
    redirect_to current_user
  end
end
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You can do `current_user.friendships.where(friend_id: params[:friend_id]).any?` to check if the user is your friend or not.

Comment: @JagjotSingh Hi Jagjot where I put this code? In my controller?

Comment: Yes in your controller before the build statement in create action. You can also use the same in your views to display some other link if the user is already a friend.

Comment: @JagjotSingh I am a newbie. but I put the code in `def create` before `@friendship = current_user.friendships.build(:friend_id => params[:friend_id])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in your controller:

```
...
def create
  if current_user.friendships.where(friend_id: params[:friend_id]).any?
    flash[:error] = "You already have added this user."
    redirect_to current_user
  else
    @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(:friend_id => params[:friend_id])
    if @friendship.save
      flash[:notice] = "Added friend."
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      flash[:error] = "Unable to add friend."
      redirect_to current_user
    end
  end
end
...
```

And in your views you can do something like this:

```
...
if current_user.id == user.id
  link_to 'Your Profile', '#!'
elsif current_user.friendships.where(friend_id: user.id).any?
  link_to 'Friends', '#!'
else
  link_to 'Add Friend', path_here
end
...
```

Comment: Great! Happy to help.

Comment: :) And I have a last question on it. And to block your auto-follow because I can Add Myself as a friend. Have you an idea to do it?

Comment: You can simply do `if current_user.friendships.where(friend_id: params[:friend_id]).any? || current_user.id == params[:friend_id] `

Comment: Thank you It is tottally new. I put it in the controller?

Comment: Yes you put in it in the controller.

Comment: Thanks but the added doesn't block when I added as friend I want to block this action when I click on my profile

Comment: Where did you add it?

Comment: `def create
  if current_user.friendships.where(friend_id: params[:friend_id]).any? || current_user.id == params[:friend_id]
    flash[:notice] = "You already have added this user."
    redirect_to users_path
  else
    @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(:friend_id => params[:friend_id])
    if @friendship.save
      flash[:notice] = "Added friend."
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      flash[:error] = "Unable to add friend."
      redirect_to current_user
    end
  end
end`

Comment: Do you want to hide the link or want to prevent the action?

Comment: I want to hide the link yes

Comment: Oh okay! Then including the controller change you need to add the condition in your HTML too. Should I edit the answer to show it?

Comment: It would be great. If I see your method I understand it.

Comment: Thank you you are efficient. A last question when I  add my profil user as a friends it diplay in my show view. I want it notices You added you, you can't and the link block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107470/discussion-between-jagjot-singh-and-baptiste-b).

Comment: Hey I have a problem I want to add a link which go to their profile when I add as Friend. I don't understand because i try a some combinations and there is undefined method                                                        `<% link_to friendship.friend(@user) do %>
     <%=h image_tag friendship.friend.picture %>
<% end %>`

Comment: I have another problem :( I want to add a link which go to their profile when I add as Friend. I don't understand because i try a some combinations and there is undefined method                                                        `<% link_to friendship.friend(@user) do %>
     <%=h image_tag friendship.friend.picture %>
<% end %>`

Comment: I don't know how to create the path when I click on picture I go to his/her user/ show view.

Comment: Nothing works `<% link_to @user(friend_id: params[:friend_id]) do %>
                    <%=h image_tag friendship.friend.picture || "http://api.adorable.io/avatars/300/#{friendship.friend.email}" %>
                  <% end %>`

Comment: I am available in chat, you can message me there.